# Conflicting jQuery Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have the following code. The problem thats occuring here is that the first function requires the linked js and css, the second requires a jQuery and javascript file that is inherited from base.html, but the loading files conflict (I believe this is because you can only run off of one jQuery file?). When I include the linked js and css files, my console throws "TypeError: $(...).formset is not a function". When I remove the linked files it throws a "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

## Code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( '[id$="date"]').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "1975:+0", dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        $( '[id$="date_earned"]').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "1975:+0", dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        $( '[id$="due"]').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "1975:+0", dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        $( '[id$="red_badge"]').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "1975:+0", dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    });
</script>

<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#formset_{{ forloop.counter0 }}").formset({
                        animateForms: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

So to have two versions of jQuery available on the same page, you can bind a jquery instance to a variable using jQuery.noConflict() using the techniques found **[here](http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page/)**.